# how to access Jenkins environment variables with DSL?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

As the question says. I can't access it.

**Tries:**

***#1:***

```
def env = System.getenv()
def BUILD_NUMBER= env["BUILD_NUMBER"]
```

***Result:***

Null when I access BUILD_NUMBER

***#2:***

```
def BUILD_NUMBER= params["BUILD_NUMBER"]
```

***Result:***

Null when I access BUILD_NUMBER
This solution however works for environment variables I create

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out the answer: `build.environment.get("BUILD_NUMBER")`

Comment: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: sorry can't help with that, I'm not at the same place and to now work with Jenkins anymore

Comment: @kylestephens Add the following line before it `build = Thread.currentThread().executable`

Answer (score 8):

This will work with recent versions of Jenkins and DSL plugin:

```
def BUILD_NUMBER = getBinding().getVariables().BUILD_NUMBER
```

Comment: Yields "Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.Binding getVariables" on the corporate Jenkins I use (version unknown)

Comment: That's a permission issue. Please check with your Jenkins administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Just to let you all know I tried with

```
def foo = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("FOO")
println "FOO=$foo"
```

It worked.
Refer the example here
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

Comment: In recent versions you need to do `def previousBuild = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild(); def foo = previousBuild.buildVariables["YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME"]`

Comment: @tftd `ERROR: (script, line 1) No such property: currentBuild for class: script`

Comment: Probably an old version of Jenkins / DSL / Pipeline

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'Build No: ' + env.BUILD_NUMBER + '. Build URL: ' + env.BUILD_URL
```

List of environment variables accessible via:
http://HOST/PATH_TO_JENKINS/env-vars.html/

e.g.,
http://localhost:8888/jenkins/env-vars.html/

Comment: Only way posted here working for me in pipeline stage

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins ver. 2.138.2

def gitUrl = binding.variables.get("GITLAB_URL")